# What is the purpose of the XML Doctype file in a DotNetNuke Skins folder?

Tags: xml, dotnetnuke, doctype, skin, dotnetnuke-9

I noticed this XML file in the DNN skins folder. Does this set the document type for a specific skin page in DotNetNuke? What will happen if a page does not have an XML file?

[image]

When I open the XML file I notice this:

[image]

Comment: If the file does not exist DNN will just revert to it's default DocType.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the context of web pages,the doctype declaration refers to a
>   Document Type Definition (DTD). The DTD specifies the rules for the
>   markup language, so that the browsers can render the content follows
>   the rules of that markup language i.e. different versions of the
>   doctype render content in different ways.
>
> In early versions of DotNetNuke the doctype was a fixed part of
>   default.aspx and was set to "HTML 4.0 Transitional" which was not
>   ideal for sites wanting to create valid XHTML markup. With 4.4, the
>   declaration has been made dynamic, to allow users to declare
>   particular doctypes with particular skins.

Source: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/doctype